# ExpressJS & Multer - req.body returns [Object: null prototype] {} when uploading file

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, multer

I have a route to upload files and I'm using `multer` as a middleware.

### Express Server Code:

```
const multer = require("multer");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}));

const multerUpload = multer();
const multerMiddleware = multerUpload.single('post_file');

app.post('/setupPictures', multerMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send({"status" : "200"});
})
```

### JQuery AJAX Code

```
var formData = new FormData();
var myFile = $(`#myFileInput`)[0].files[0];
formData.append('post_file', myFile)

$.ajax({
    url: `https://example.com/setupPictures`, 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

I'm uploading a `.jpg` file.

Upon sending the request, it responded with `{"status" : "200"}`. Also upon checking the Chrome's Network tab, the payload did indeed got sent.
[image]

### Problem

However, on the Server, it output the following:

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

### Desired Output

Is there a solution ? I've been searching online and it seems that the desired output should be as such:

```
[Object: null prototype] { post_file: 'example.jpg' }
```

### Extra

I tried adding `req.files` & `req.file`
However they both returned `undefined`

Comment: Try to add `  enctype: "multipart/form-data",' in your ajax request